# Text fields in Table View Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am working on this app, and I am new to Swift. Only two weeks of knowledge. I am supposed to create a table view with 12 cells - 3 of which are  supposed to be text fields and user can type what they want. I have made two prototype cells with two different identifiers. I am using an array called "items" which has strings to be represented in the cells. If the string is blank, that cell is supposed to be a text field, which I have done. Problem occurs after that when I try to type in those fields and scroll the cells.

Please help me in understanding and solving the following issues:

1. How can I delegate the text field which  I added as a subview to my tableview cell?
2. How can I make sure that whatever I type in the textfield remains there, even after I scroll the cells up and down as I wish?
3. How can I make sure user can edit whatever they type in the text field?

Here is my code:

```
    var items = ["Apple", "Fish", "Dates", "Cereal", "Ice cream", "Lamb", "Potatoes", "Chicken", "Bread", " ", " "," "]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var iD = "normal"
    if (items[indexPath.row] == " ") {
        iD = "textField"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(iD, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 150, height: 30))
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        textField.placeholder = ""         
        cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
        return cell      
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(iD, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell  
    }
```

////

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (sourceIndexPath.row != destinationIndexPath.row){
        let temp = items[sourceIndexPath.row]
        items.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        items.insert(temp, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep to one question per post otherwise it `a)` becomes difficult to create an answer and `b)` it will be difficult for you to select a "correct" answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather create a subclass of UITableviewCell and add a textfield there as a subview. Then you set the delegate of the textfield to the cell itself. 
Here is some sample code. I did not try to run it, but i think it should work:

```
class InputCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

private let textField = UITextField()
private var resultBlock: ((changedText: String) -> ())? = nil

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.textField.delegate = self
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.textField)
    // additional setup for the textfield like setting the textstyle and so on
}

func setup(initalText: String, resultBlock: (changedText: String) -> ()) {
    self.textField.text = initalText
    self.resultBlock = resultBlock
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if let block = self.resultBlock, let text = textField.text {
        block(changedText: text)
    }
}
}
```

In your view controller i would change the items to be a dictionary, so you can directly link them to the indexpaths of the tableview. And you need to let the tableview register your custom cell class.

```
var items = [0: "Apple", 1: "Fish", 2: "Dates", 3: "Cereal", 4: "Ice cream", 5: "Lamb", 6: "Potatoes", 7: "Chicken", 8: "Bread", 9: " ", 10: " ", 11: " "]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // the position of the cell with a textfield is fixed right? Just put the row number here then
    if indexPath.row > 8 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellWithTextField", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InputCell
        if let initialText = items[indexPath.row] {
            cell.setup(initialText) { [weak self] text in
                self?.items[indexPath.row] = text
            }
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NormalCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! how do I connect the delegate of textfield to cell itself? and do I need to create a textField in  the storyboard or is it done in the code?

Comment: In my example the delegate of the textfield is already set (in the init of the cell). Also the textfield is already there, you would have to constrain it or give it a frame though to make it show up

Answer (score 0):

first, add the textfield protocol UITextFielDelegate, and in cell for row atindex write textfield.delegate = self.

And add delegate method to manage the text.

Hope this help you.

Comment: do you mean that while defining the class, I should call UITextFieldDelegate along with those of tableview's? also, can you explain more on delegate method please?

Comment: like yourclass: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {                             func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.text)
    }

Comment: Thank you. This is what I did: class MainScreen : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate{       ---- but I cannot call those delegate functions. how do I use them inside my cellforRowIndex func?

Comment: In your textfield delegate method, you can save your text, use them later for display in text field or edit.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit UITextFieldDelegate to your controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var iD = "normal"
if (items[indexPath.row] == " ") {
    iD = "textField"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(iD, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 150, height: 30))
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    textField.placeholder = ""         
    cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
    textField.delegate = self // set delegate
    textField.tag= indexPath.row
    return cell      
}
else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(iD, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell  
  }
}

 //delegate methods

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {      //delegate method
  print(textField.tag)//you will get the row. items[textField.tag] will get the object

 }
 func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
  print(textField.tag)//you will get the row. items[textField.tag] will get the object
  items[textField.tag]= textField.text
  return false
}

 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {     //delegate method
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return true
 }
```

Comment: where should I use these delegate methods? Inside my cellForRowIndex function?

Comment: can you please give me an example of how i can link textfields and celltexts together? by same controller, you mean the class right?

Comment: is your cell is dynamic? you need to tag textfields .

Comment: you should set a tag to identfy which row textfield edited . i will update

Comment: i did what you suggested. but it is only editing in one text field. not all three of them. it lets me choose any of the three fields to edit, but once i start editing, it doesn't let me edit any other. what's the problem?

Comment: i didnt understand

Comment: i can only edit one text field. i am supposed to have textfield in three cells. but i can only edit the text in one cell. idk why

Comment: as @Aks mentioned that you have to store the textfield field data after editing.i updated

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the textfield data in some object. As UITableView reuses same cells your textfield text will be lost on scroll as the cell will be reused. I would suggest creating some array and storing the data in that for each indexPath.

You should implement the UITextField delegate methods inside cell class and whenever some text changes, you should call another delegate method of yours (CellDelegate) which should be implemented in ViewController  to update data.

This delegate method will pass text and indexPath of cell.

Comment: this is where I am getting totally lost. I don't know how to store it some sort of array and then linking it to those specific cells for which the text from textfield is meant to be. Can you please suggest some sort of example in code for the all the solutions you suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

In the UITableViewCell add the UItextfield delegate for textChange. 
You can alter your items array to contain model objects having the real value and the editing value.

```
let apple = Item()
apple.realValue = "Apple"
apple.editedValue = ""

var item = [0: apple, .............
```

Pass the model object in the tableview cell and update the edited value on text change delegate call. In cellForRow add the editedValue in the textfield text property

```
let item = items[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = item.realValue
if item.editedValue{
// add the textFieldText
```

}